# Why doesn't my KendoGrid call my MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have the following code in a standard C# ASP.NET MVC controller.

```
public JsonResult ReadTeachers()
{
    return Json(ReadTeacherData(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public void UpdateTeachers(IEnumerable<Teacher> updatedTeachers)
{
    // this is never called
}
```

I'm trying to call this controller with a KendoGrid. Here is the code for my grid.

```
$("#teachers").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("ReadTeachers", "EducationPortal")',
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTeachers", "EducationPortal")',
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "TeacherId",
                fields: {
                    TeacherId: { type: "number" },
                    FullName: { type: "string" },
                    IsHeadmaster: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    toolbar: ["create", "save"],
    columns: [
        { field: "FullName", title: "Teacher" },
        { field: "IsHeadmaster", title: "Is a Headmaster?", width: "120px" },
        { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "85px" }],
    editable: true
});
```

I adapted this code from Kendo's [examples](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing.html). The problem is, the UpdateTeachers method is never called. I suspect that the issue lies in the parameterMap function, because that's the part of the code I understand the least.

Comment: If you check in the browser dev tools, is any network request sent when you edit a record and click the "save" button? Wondering if the client doesn't send a request at all, or the URL is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using

```
public void UpdateTeachers(IEnumerable<Teacher> updatedTeachers)
{
    // this is never called
}
```

used

```
public JsonResult UpdateTeachers(string models)
{
//Deserialize to object
IList<Teacher> teachers= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<Teacher>>(models);

return Json(Teacher)
}
```

Note that parameterMap: function() send updated data in serialize string format with name **models** so you should use "models" as parameter name in your action

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I kept rechecking my grid thinking I had made a mistake there. It turned out that my problem was in the object I was passing into the grid: my object's Id was not set when it was passed in.

I checked in Fiddler, and the POST was still being made, but without the object's ID my controller didn't recognize the parameters, thus not hitting my action.

Make sure the objects returned by your read action have their properties set.