# Kendo Grid how to datasource update,create,delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

For some reasons I cannot use MVC-wrapper of Kendo grid. So I am trying to build Kendo grid on JavaScript.

There are 2 main problems when trying to update or create records on grid.

1-)All operations(destroy,update,create) on grid just go to create action by Datasource's of Kendo grid. For example after update a record, datasource send data to this URL to many times(number of columns):
`http://localhost:63186/Administrator/DefinitionDetailCreate`. It should pass values to:

```
http://localhost:63186/Administrator/DefinitionDetailUpdate
```

2-)After operation(update or create) Grid sends all data to Action Method instead of new or updated data. So it sends requests the number of columns on grid

**JavaScript**:

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
var code = dataItem.CODE;
// alert(code);

var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/Administrator/",
  dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailRead", "Administrator")',
        data: {DefinitionCode: code},

        dataType: "json"
      },
      update: {
        url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailUpdate", "Administrator")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text"
      },
      destroy: {
        url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailDelete", "Administrator")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
      },
      create: {
        url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailCreate", "Administrator")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",

      }
    },
    // batch: true,
    pageSize: 9,

    schema: {
      data: "Data",
      model: {

        ID: "ID",
        fields: {
          ID: {editable: false, nullable: true},
          DESCRIPTION: {validation: {required: true}}
        }
      }
    }
  });

$("#detailsGrid").kendoGrid({

  dataSource: dataSource,
  attributes: {style: "padding-left: 0px; font-size: 14px"},
  pageable: {refresh: false, pageSizes: false, buttonCount: 5},
  toolbar: ["create"],
  columns: [
    {field: "DESCRIPTION", title: "DESCRIPTION", width: "200px"},
    {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operasyon", width: "100px"}],
  editable: "popup"
});
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DefinitionDetailUpdate(Guid ID,Guid REFERENCEID,string DESCRIPTION)
{
  return null;

}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DefinitionDetailCreate(Guid ID, Guid REFERENCEID, string DESCRIPTION)
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: If you cant use the MVC wrappers your missing something. Have you added the Kendo UI namespace to the Web Config in the views Folder? Or throw a `@using Kendo.Mvc.UI` at the top of your view

Answer (score 1):

First you might need to add [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap), this will help identify server side methods:

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
var out = null;
switch (operation) {
    case "create":
        out = '{ "param":' + options.somevalue + '}';
        break;
    case "read":
        out = '{ "id":' + options.somevalue + '}';
        break;
    case "update":
        out = '{ "id":' + options.somevalue + '}';
        break;
    case "destroy":
        out = '{ "id":  ' + options.somevalue + '}';
        break;
}
return out;
```

}

I would also suggest to keep all the dataTypes as `dataType: "json"`

Also you seem to be missing `contentType` in your transports definitions :

```
  update: {
                            url: _op.serviceBaseUrl + "Update",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            complete: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {

                            }
                        },
```

Comment: When i add  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", nothing is catch by Action Method but some data posted.When i add paramaterMap option , no data coming from read method.Think i need to solve with Kendo Mvc-Wrapper

Answer (score 0):

i have posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546978/why-doesnt-my-kendogrid-call-my-mvc-controller/22573989#22573989) for the same type of question, you may have a check

or

you may Use this code

js

```
 var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
            var code = dataItem.CODE;
           // alert(code);

            var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/Administrator/",
                         dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                             transport: {
                                 read: {

                                 url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailRead", "Administrator")',
    type: "POST",
                                     dataType: "json"
                                 },
                                 update: {
                                     url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailUpdate", "Administrator")' ,
                                     type: "POST",
                                     dataType: "json"
                                 },
                                 destroy: {
                                     url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailDelete", "Administrator")',
                                     type: "POST",
                                     dataType: "json",
                                 },
                                 create: {
                                     url: '@Url.Action("DefinitionDetailCreate", "Administrator")',
                                     type: "POST",
                                     dataType: "json",

                                 },
                                  parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                  if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                  return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                  }
                              } },
                            // batch: true,
                             pageSize: 9,

                             schema: {
                                 data: "Data",
                                 model: {

                                     ID: "ID",
                                     fields: {
                                         ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                         DESCRIPTION: { validation: { required: true } }


                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         });

            $("#detailsGrid").kendoGrid({

                dataSource: dataSource,
                attributes: { style: "padding-left: 0px; font-size: 14px"},
                pageable: {refresh: false, pageSizes: false, buttonCount: 5},
                toolbar: ["create"],
                columns: [
                    {field: "DESCRIPTION", title: "DESCRIPTION", width: "200px"},
                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operasyon", width: "100px" }],
                editable: "popup"
            });
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DefinitionDetailUpdate(string models)
    {
   //Deserialize to object
    IList<UrObjectType> objName= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<UrObjectType>>(models);

     return Json(objName)


    }
    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult DefinitionDetailCreate(string models)
     {
         //Deserialize to object
    IList<UrObjectType> objName= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<UrObjectType>>(models);

     return Json(objName)

     }
```

Note that parameterMap: function() send updated data in serialize string format with name models so you should use "**models**" as parameter name in your action

i hope this will help you:)